# Difference between pip install . and pip install -e

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have created a package in python, and now I would like to install it as a regular package. 
What is the difference between just using `pip3 install .` and `pip3 install -e .` ?

The reason why I asked, is because with pip3 install . the package, although installed was not seen by the system. While in the second way it was working fine

Comment: [this is documented](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-editable)

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? Did ``pip install --help`` not provide enough information?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's clearly documented

Comment: I am right now running in the same issue: `pip install -e .` and everything works fine. But with `pip install .` "ModuleNotFoundError". Nothing in documentation explains this; there is even a page for this with nothing about it: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/local-project-installs/

Comment: Make sure you include the subpackages in your `setup.py`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-e` flag tells pip to install in editable mode:

```
-e,--editable <path/url>
    Install a project in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode") from a local project path or a VCS url.
```

https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/python-pip/pip.1

So what is editable mode or setuptools "develop mode" ?

> This command allows you to deploy your project’s source for use in one
>   or more “staging areas” where it will be available for importing. This
>   deployment is done in such a way that changes to the project source
>   are immediately available in the staging area(s), without needing to
>   run a build or install step after each change.
>
> The develop command works by creating an .egg-link file (named for the
>   project) in the given staging area. If the staging area is Python’s
>   site-packages directory, it also updates an easy-install.pth file so
>   that the project is on sys.path by default for all programs run using
>   that Python installation.
>
> The develop command also installs wrapper scripts in the staging area
>   (or a separate directory, as specified) that will ensure the project’s
>   dependencies are available on sys.path before running the project’s
>   source scripts. And, it ensures that any missing project dependencies
>   are available in the staging area, by downloading and installing them
>   if necessary.
>
> Last, but not least, the develop command invokes the build_ext -i
>   command to ensure any C extensions in the project have been built and
>   are up-to-date, and the egg_info command to ensure the project’s
>   metadata is updated (so that the runtime and wrappers know what the
>   project’s dependencies are). If you make any changes to the project’s
>   setup script or C extensions, you should rerun the develop command
>   against all relevant staging areas to keep the project’s scripts,
>   metadata and extensions up-to-date.

or, tldr;

> Deploy your project in “development mode”, such that it’s available on
>   sys.path, yet can still be edited directly from its source checkout.

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode