# What is the difference between a "pip wheel -e" and "pip install -e"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

Building a C-extension library to python, I noticed that building it with with `wheel` (and then `install` the `*.whl`) versus a direct `install`, gives very different results and build artifacts.

##### Building with: `pip install -e .`

- We get an entry for `Editable project location` in the `pip list` results
- The buildi atrifacts are few, but contains `*.egg-info` folder.

```bash
# pip install -e . --no-cache-dir
# pip list

Package            Version     Editable project location
------------------ ----------- -----------------------------------------------
black-scholes      0.0.1       C:\path-to\fbs

# tree -L 3
.
├── docs
├── examples
│   └── fbs_test.py
├── src
│   ├── black_scholes
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── fbs.pyd
│   ├── black_scholes.egg-info
│   │   ├── PKG-INFO
│   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   │   └── top_level.txt
│   └── lib
│       ├── Makefile
│       └── fbs.c
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.py
```

##### Building with: `pip wheel -e .`

However, when first building with *wheel* and then installing, we get a very different result.

- We get an entire `build` directory with lots of artifacts.
- `Editable project location` is empty

```bash
# pip wheel -e . --no-cache-dir
# pip install black_scholes-0.0.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl

# tree -L 6
.
├── build
│   ├── bdist.win-amd64
│   ├── lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
│   │   ├── black_scholes
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── fbs.pyd
│   │   └── lib
│   │       └── fbs.c
│   └── temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
│       └── Release
│           └── src
│               └── lib
│                   ├── fbs.exp
│                   ├── fbs.lib
│                   └── fbs.obj
├── docs
├── examples
│   └── fbs_test.py
├── src
│   ├── black_scholes
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── black_scholes.egg-info
│   │   ├── PKG-INFO
│   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   │   └── top_level.txt
│   └── lib
│       ├── Makefile
│       └── fbs.c
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── black_scholes-0.0.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.py
```

Q: **What's going on, and how is `pip` doing this differently?**

(Is there a way to do the `pip install`, *step-by-step*?)

**References:**

- [This SOA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60638497/1147688) - But still not very clear as it just refers back to *setuptools* [docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode)

Comment: Isn't the C extension build in a temporary directory when installing directly? Similar to your explicit wheel build, but in a scratch directory that is removed after the installation. Check with a verbose option to see what happens.

Comment: Aside: I don't think the `-e` option has any relevance here: without it, you would see the same.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: the wheel  *builds* a binary installable Python package (binary where relevant), without installing it. The install command *installs* the package, compiling it if necessary.

Comment: I noticed that `pip wheel -e .` and `pip wheel .` seem to do the same thing (or nothing). As according to above SO link, the `-e` is supposed to make it *"editable"*. using it on the regular `pip install -e .` ensures it end up with an `Editable project location`. I never understood what is an *editable project* or when it would be used. I don't think the people documenting it knows either, as it seem so poorly documented.

Comment: Ah, I found some better hints [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/devmode.html) and [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html). This is what I though, that you should be able to edit the (python) files in the project directory/repo **after** having been installed. Basically the package is pointing to your repo.

Comment: As said: *"...to facilitate iterative exploration and experimentation, setuptools allows users to instruct the Python interpreter and its import machinery to load the code under development directly from the project folder without having to copy the files to a different location in the disk. This means that changes in the Python source code can immediately take place without requiring a new installation."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in summary:

- `pip install -e .` makes your installed (*live*) package `Editable`, by pointing and using the *local* (package project) directory for all it's files. This way you can edit the package files and see the results immediately.
- `pip wheel -e .` ignores the `-e` flag because it **only builds** the wheel,  (in your local directory) and does not install the package. Therefore the `-e` is redundant.

<sub>PS. I am not 100% on the ignoring part, but I cannot see any difference from not using it. It could have additional functionalities not documented.</sub>